# How can I disable the automatic checking for updates when Google App Engine Launcher is started?

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine

I've been tinkering with the GAE and I enjoy the ease of use of the GAE Launcher that is available with the Windows SDK.

My problem is that when I start the application, it takes it a long time for it to become responsive.  This is because the program first checks for updates before starting the app.  This causes it to hang, while it's waiting for a response.  My problem is that my primary dev machine is behind a proxy server, and the GAE Launcher is being blocked by the proxy.

Is there a way that I can disable the check for updates to the GAE when I start the launcher?  Maybe a command that I can pass to the underlying executable through my shortcut?

Comment: Try clearing your development datastore (if that's feasible in your case).

Comment: My datastore is clear.  To be sure, the hanging takes place when I double-click on the launcher application icon-- not when I try to start a project.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Google App Engine (GAE) use the python [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) library to check for updates. This library gets the proxy settings from `*_proxy` environment variables, instead of the windows registry.

> By default, ProxyHandler uses the environment variables named <scheme>_proxy, where <scheme> is the URL scheme involved. For example, the http_proxy environment variable is read to obtain the HTTP proxy’s URL.

If you need to use a proxy and don't have this variable properly defined, your GAE Launcher will lock until a connection timeout, delaying the start of the program.

If you create a new environment variable called `http_proxy` with `host_or_ip:port`, GAE Launcher will start in a blink of an eye.

To define an environment variable, go to: `Control Panel -> System and Security -> System -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced Tab -> Environment Variables...`

Comment: Aha, Brilliant! This worked exactly as you stated.  This has been annoying me for years.

Comment: Haha, i'm glad i helped :D, actually surlac's solution worked for me, but i didn't like changing the source code, besides, my solution will fix other python applications and self-written code.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure all your GAE-java/python processes are shutted down before you fork new ones. It's very often that they stuck and consume processor time and memory after you hit CTRL+C.

---

[EDIT]

To disable updates run the server with

```
--disable_update_check
```

option.

> Usage: <dev-appserver> [options]
>   <war directory>

---

[EDIT]

Open **dev_appserver.cmd** script from GAE SDK with your favorite text processor and manually add **--disable_update_check** option right after *DevAppServerMain* definition.

```
java -cp "%~dp0\..\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar" ^
com.google.appengine.tools.KickStart ^
   com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain --disable_update_check %*
```

Next time you'll run an application from the GAE Launcher, it will start with "--disable_update_check" option automatically.

---

[EDIT]

For Python:

open python source code at

> [GAE_SDK_PY]/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py

with your favorite text processor, find a 227-th line, it looks like

ARG_SKIP_SDK_UPDATE_CHECK: False,

and overwrite it with following:

```
  ARG_SKIP_SDK_UPDATE_CHECK: True,
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That would work if I was running the server from a console window.  Passing the --disable_update_check option to the App Engine Launcher does not help.  There may not be a way to fix this problem.  I can accept that, however, this issue is a bit annoying.

Comment: To work around this issue you need to manually edit "dev_appserver.cmd" script as described in the answer.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Is there a python equivalent?

Comment: You need to update dev_appserver_main.py according to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  That has fixed the dev server, but the launcher still hangs when I start it.  I'm marking this response as the answer because I'm assuming that the real problem must come from another issue.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: There isn't --disable_update_check option in python SDK. Use --skip_sdk_update_check instead.

Answer (score 4):

As an update, the currently working option with `Google App Engine 1.9.19` is to edit the file  `~/.appcfg_nag` to make the following change.

```
- opt_in: true
+ opt_in: false
  timestamp: 0.0
```

I found about this by consulting the
`google_appengine/README:line 120`

```
--skip_sdk_update_check    Skip checking for SDK updates. If false, fall back                                                                                     
                           to opt_in setting specified in .appcfg_nag          
                           (Default false)
```