# App deployment using Google App Engine in Win7 with a connection requiring Proxy with Authentication

Tags: windows, google-app-engine, deployment, proxy

I am behind unversity proxy which also requires authentication. I am a beginner in learning app-development and I have tried a lot many forum posts on stack overflow and at developers.google for app deployment using GAE in Win7 with a connection requiring proxy with Authentication but in vain. I have used "set http_proxy....." command in cmd window but it never asked me for authentication.

Everytime, I get an error no 10060 Connection timed out

Here is what I get in ' Deploying to Google(Myapp) Window ' --

```
2012-05-18 11:59:26 Running command: "['C:\\Python27\\python.exe', '-u', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\google_appengine\\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=aaaagrawal@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', u'C:\\webapp\\arbitx']"
Application: arbitx; version: 1
Host: appengine.google.com

Starting update of app: arbitx, version: 1
Getting current resource limits.
2012-05-18 12:03:36,849 ERROR appcfg.py:2156 An error occurred processing file '': <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 125, in <module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 121, in run_file
    execfile(script_path, globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4062, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4053, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2543, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3810, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3006, in Update
    self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2995, in UpdateVersion
    self.options.max_size)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2122, in DoUpload
    resource_limits = GetResourceLimits(self.rpcserver, self.config)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 355, in GetResourceLimits
    resource_limits.update(GetRemoteResourceLimits(rpcserver, config))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 326, in GetRemoteResourceLimits
    version=config.version)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 366, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", line 367, in do_open
    raise url_error
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond>
2012-05-18 12:03:36 (Process exited with code 1)

You can close this window now.
```

A step by step instruction for dealing with proxy(with authentication) and deployment in Win7 will be much appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: please refrain from stuff like "URGENT HELP"

Comment: does your proxy work for other programs like your browser? also does the proxy allow arbitrary ports (or protocols) or only special ports like 80 (HTTP) or 443 (HTTPS) ?

Comment: also consider asking your universities admin for help. by the way this question is better suited for http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not marking this as a duplicate since you are trying to use the Google App Engine API via the console window, rather than the GAE Launcher.  However, please try to follow the advice given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468191/google-app-engine-launcher-slow-to-launch-behind-proxy-possibly-because-of-ch) I posted about a year ago.

In short, you need to setup an environment variable on your machine named `HTTP_PROXY` and it's value needs to be `host_or_ip:port`.

I work with a company that has a proxy server that I, too, must authenticate through.  So long as I am authenticated on my machine, this method has worked without the need for authenticating when posting my request.

If this still doesn't work, you could try modify the the value of `HTTP_PROXY` to `username:password@host_or_ip:port`.  I haven't tried this (and can't at the moment) but that might work if your proxy server accepts such requests.